# How get participants with jpa?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

i have this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Participant")
public class Participant {

    @Column(name = "user")
    User user;

    @Column(name = "meet")
    Meet meet;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "rol")
    Rol rol;
```

And class Meet is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Meet")
public class Meet implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true, name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "state")
    private State state;
```

i want get participats through meet

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Participant p where p.meet= :id")
    Participant findByMeet(@Param("id") Long id);
```

How do I get the list of participants that belong in the Meet

Comment: what is this `Meet`?

Comment: @Deadpool is a  class, It's a set of users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an `@Id` of `Long` in `Participant` it should just be something like this.

```
@Repository
public interface ParticipantRepository implements CrudRepository<Participant, Long> {
  List<Participant> findAllByMeet(Meet meet);
}
```

Spring Data will provide the implementation dynamically for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add the fileds in the domain model.

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "Participant")
public class Participant {

    @Column(name = "user")
    User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @Column(name = "meet_id") // It's a foreign key of Participant 
    Meet meet;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "rol")
     Rol rol;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Meet")
public class Meet implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true, name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "state")
    private State state;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Meet", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Participant> participants = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Comment: this is good ManyToOne
    Column(name = "meet_id")? 
I think it should be onetoone?

Comment: Depends on your domain entity relation. Because of I thought it's @ManyToOne between Meet and Participant in your design.